# Java compilation error cannot find symbol of interface

Tags: java, class, inheritance, interface, compiler-errors

I am trying to implement an interface in my java code as such:

```
package PJ1;

public class Fraction implements FractionInterface, Comparable<Fraction>{
```

Now, FractionInterface.class in the same directory as the Fraction.java file, and it is also in package PJ1:

```
package PJ1;

public interface FractionInterface{
```

Yet when I try to compile my Fraction.java file, I get the following error:

```
D:\CSC220\PJ1\Fraction.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
public class Fraction implements FractionInterface, Comparable<Fraction>
                                 ^
```

I'm stumped, since all of my related files are in the same directory and I'm trying to put all of my class files in the same package.  Any ideas?

Comment: as u say that files are in same directory - then check for spelling error

Comment: I checked, and there are no spelling errors.  Thanks though.

Comment: The error points for line 36, so could you show some more code?

Comment: here is line 36, same as above   `public class Fraction implements FractionInterface, Comparable<Fraction>{`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the files are not in a directory called `PJ1` relative to where the compiler expects them to be. Create the folder and move both files to that location. To make it a bit clearer, let's say your folder structure looks like this

```
myfolder
 +-PJ1
    Fraction.java
    FractionInterface.java
```

Then you need to be compiling from `myfolder` using

```
javac PJ1\Fraction.java
```

Comment: Are you compiling from the folder `PJ1`?

Comment: Wait, I think that this worked!  I went one directory above and used the command you listed above.  Turns out I have other errors, so compilation failed but I think it sees the interface now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

try to compile like this:

e.g. in c: you do have both the java files - Fraction.java and FractionInterface.java , and you have not created any folder for packages yet, then try as:

```
c:> javac -d . *.java
```

This will compile all the files with creating required packages. You no need to create any folders for packages manually.

If you already have created the folder for packages, and you are already in the package say:

c:\PJ1, you can simply compile using javac as:

```
c:\PJ1> javac *.java
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work (see above).  Though I'm not totally clear about why this worked..

Comment: Ok. But I wanted to let you know, you can also use javac with -d option so to create the packages automatically. It will reduce the burden to create the packages manually.

Any why it worked... What is your doubt/confusion?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that both files are in PJ1 folder and run `javac *.java`.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to a directory above the directory in which your files exist and compile your java files from there (so that you can see if they compile correctly), e.g.

**javac dir1\file.java.**